# ComboBox Simplifying Method

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio

I have 3 or more ComboBoxes having the same functionality. what I'm thinking is creating a Method and just call it

Here is sample code

Question: Is there any way to Combine this  5 ComboBox  into 1 since  they have the same functionality and simplify this Method if for example i'm having multiple ComboBoxes

```
    public double comboBoxTry()
    { double x;
    if (comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() == "First")
    { x = 3.5; }
    else if (comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() == "Second")
    { x = 4; }

    //Second ComboBox and so on
    if (comboBox2.SelectedItem.ToString() == "First")
    { x = 3.5; }
    else if (comboBox2.SelectedItem.ToString() == "Second")
    { x = 4; }

if (comboBox2.SelectedItem.ToString() == "First")
    { x = 3.5; }
    else if (comboBox2.SelectedItem.ToString() == "Second")
    { x = 4; }

if (comboBox3.SelectedItem.ToString() == "First")
    { x = 3.5; }
    else if (comboBox3.SelectedItem.ToString() == "Second")
    { x = 4; }

if (comboBox4.SelectedItem.ToString() == "First")
    { x = 3.5; }
    else if (comboBox4.SelectedItem.ToString() == "Second")
    { x = 4; }


if (comboBox5.SelectedItem.ToString() == "First")
    { x = 3.5; }
    else if (comboBox5.SelectedItem.ToString() == "Second")
    { x = 4; }

// I want to Combine this  5 ComboBox  into 1 since  they have the same functionality 

    return x;
    }

    private void btnCompute_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        { txtResult.Text = (x * double.Parse(txtAmount.Text)).ToString(); }
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Is this the exact logic you are using? Also, where is this code? in an event handler?

Comment: Your post is actually missing question itself. Try to elaborate more.

Comment: is there any way to simplify that code? like if im having multiple Combo Boxes

Comment: NewbieVB, You need to explain a bit more about what you are doing here.. are these 2 combo boxes in a panel? do they all have the same elements? you can make a method `GetXFromComboBox(ComboBox cb)` but its unclear how else to help without more information. Also, the code you have provided doesn't even compile since `x` is in a different scope to your click event

Comment: Edited my post again... Kindly read it once again

Comment: You can have selected item value and text. In value you can have numeric value so i dont think you need some complex code to return the value. Also you can use common functions always

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand right, when the Event is raised, you want to call comboBoxTry.

If this is what you are trying to do you don't have to. You can do it in the EventHandle, With a Switch on your comboBox.Name and then doing your tests.

```
private void btnCompute_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    { 
        double x = 0;
        switch (sender.name)
        {
            case "CombOne" :
             [Your tests]
             break;
            case "Combtwo" :
            ....
            ....
        }
        txtResult.Text = (x * double.Parse(txtAmount.Text)).ToString(); 
}
```

Edit : For your last edit, I think you could use the Tag attribute. Tagging all comboBox with the same behavior and then making your tests on the Tag.

that way you will have just

```
private void btnCompute_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        { 
            double x = 0;
            if (sender.tag == "SameBehaviorComboBox")
            {
                if (sender.SelectedItem.ToString() == "First")
                { 
                    x = 3.5; 
                }
                else if (sender.SelectedItem.ToString() == "Second")
                { 
                    x = 4; 
                }
            }
            txtResult.Text = (x * double.Parse(txtAmount.Text)).ToString(); 
    }
```

And it will work for all comboBox with the same tag.